# USB driver for android

Tags: android, usb

Is there a way to write a driver for android phone, so that when i plug it in the computer it's going to install it with the default usb drivers? I want to make a application that needs a driver to be installed on the computer to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your Android App download or contain the installer for your driver and then copy it to the SD card storage area. There is no way to get the installer to autorun because Android connects either with MPT or PTP. These can be used to access a file from the SD card, but it does not mount as an ordinary storage device. You will need to have instructions in the app to tell the user how to access it. 
Honestly, it will probably be easier to have them download it separately and install it.